# In Zencart,I want to add new fields in shop cart from the session variable

Tags: php, session, zen-cart

var_dump($_SESSION['cart']) can get object like this:

```
object(shoppingCart)[4]
  public 'contents' => 
    array
      427 => 
        array
          'qty' => float 5
  public 'total' => float 544.9
  public 'weight' => float 0
  public 'cartID' => string '85911' (length=5)
  public 'content_type' => boolean false
  public 'free_shipping_item' => float 5
  public 'free_shipping_weight' => float 7027.5
  public 'free_shipping_price' => float 544.9
```

I want to know how can I add a new field like categories_id in shoppingCart SESSION.(PS:I add item to cart as a visitor customer not register customer.)Thank you!

Comment: Try like `$_SESSION['cart']['contents']['categories_id']='someid';`

Comment: I want to know where the shoppingCart SESSION init